# Azure container registry repository not accessible while Bursting from AKS to ACI with the Virtual Kubelet

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

> api call to
>   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/75b381e6-d739-4955-2-e7e7adc/resourceGroups/MC_xxxcoreapi_CoreCluster_westeurope/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/xxx-coreapi-public-xxxcorejob1-vdjsb?api-version=2018-10-01:
>       got HTTP response status code 400 error code "InaccessibleImage": The image ''xxxx.azurecr.io/core:v1.0.0.0''
>       in container group ''xxx-coreapi-public-xxx-vdjsb'' is not accessible

**Use Case:** Bursting from AKS to ACI with the Virtual Kubelet. I am able to pull it using docker pull, also I can pull image in AKS node with and without imagePullSecret, but not with the ones type: **virtual-kubelet**

Already tried the following:

[Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

```
CreateSecret
 imagePullSecrets:
   name: xxx-axth
```

Also use service account with secret. My AKS Service principal has `contributor` and `acrpull` roles

Furthermore I have tried:

```
az aks update -n CoreCluster -g xxxcoreapi --attach-acr xxxcoreapi"
```

Comment: that is really weird. that should work

Comment: @4c74356b41 apparently yes, I spent entire day figuring this out, but no luck

Comment: How do you create the AKS cluster? The portal or other ways?

Comment: @CharlesXu I created it through portal, and enable the auto scaling with aci under scale tab from the portal.

Additionally I installed helm and run the following command as well

az aks install-connector --name CoreCluster --resource-group coreapi

Comment: Which network type do you use? The basic or the advance?

Comment: @CharlesXu basic

Comment: Are you really sure you use the basic network in the portal to create the AKS cluster? As I know it only supports the advance network when you enable the virtual node.

Comment: @CharlesXu my mistake "you are correct"
I have following setting
Network type (plugin): Advanced (Azure CNI)

Comment: @CharlesXu may be it has something to do with new resource group that is created automatically "MC_coreapi_CoreJobCluster_westeurope"

Comment: OK, then do you grant the service principal of the AKS cluster with the right permission of the Vnet you use for the virtual node?

Comment: @CharlesXu I did it using following command.
where assignee = cluster service principal app id
az role assignment create --assignee 0dc88dc1-b533-4143-bf5c- --scope /subscriptions/75b381e6--4955-8f82-e7cc1b7e7adc/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxx-vnet --role Contributor

Answer (score 0):

So it is resolved finally

Strange enough, I log out to the azure portal, restart my pc, and everything working as expected.

As per my understanding possible causes are

- Azure refresh cache thing
- My computer cache refresh for related files/config

I hope that my experience will help somebody with similar situation